# Vue 3 new instance of .vue file

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

In vue 2 i can easy create an instance:
let vueTemplate = new template();

and it would work. But it doesn't work in vue 3.

This is the code in Vue 2 how i can access a new instance:

```js
import template from './edit-text-field.vue';

export default class EditTextFieldInitializer {
    public static InitEditTextField(config: EditTextFieldConfig) {
     // VueConstructor
     let vueTemplate = new template(); // How can i do the same in vue 3 ?
     vueTemplate .$mount(config.element);
  }
}
```

error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _edit_text_field_vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default is not a constructor
```

my templete vue file:

```
<template>
    <el-form :model="form" :rules="rules" ref="form" label-width="0px"
             @submit.prevent
             @validate="onValidate"
             class="gantt-text-field-edit-form"
             v-loading="isLoading">
        <el-form-item prop="value">
            <el-popover placement="bottom"
                        v-model="isPopoverVisible"
                        width="200"
                        trigger="manual"
                        :content="errorMessage">
                                      <template #reference>
                <el-input  ref="input" @blur="submitForm"
                          :placeholder="$l('PleaseEnterValue')" v-model="form.value"></el-input>
                                        </template>
            </el-popover>

        </el-form-item>

    </el-form>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
export default defineComponent({
        name: 'edit-text-field',
        data: () => {
            return {
                isPopoverVisible: false,
                isGettingErrorMsg: false,
                errorMessage: null,
                isFormSubmited: false,
                isLoading: false,
                form: {
                    value: null
                },
                rules: {

                },
                onValueChanged: null,
                onEditModeExit: null

            }
        },
        methods: {
            onChanged(value) {
                this.submitForm();
            },
            setData(data) {
                this.form = data.form;
                this.rules = data.rules;
                this.onValueChanged = data.onValueChanged;
                this.onEditModeExit = data.onEditModeExit;
            },
            onBlur() {
                this.$beforeUnmount();
                this.$data.onEditModeExit();
            },
            processInput(event: any): void {
                if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                    this.submitForm();
                }
            },
            processEscButtonPress(event: any): void {
                //esc button
                if (event.keyCode === 27) {
                    this.onBlur();
                }
            },
            submitForm() {
                let component: any = this;
                if (component.$data.isFormSubmited)
                    return;
                component.$data.isFormSubmited = true;
                component.$refs.form.validate((valid) => {
                    if (valid) {
                        component.setFormValid();
                        var promise = component.$data.onValueChanged(component.$data.form.value);
                        if (promise == null) {
                            component.onBlur();
                            component.$data.isFormSubmited = false;
                        } else {
                            component.$data.isLoading = true;
                            promise.then(() => {
                                component.$data.isFormSubmited = false;
                                component.$data.isLoading = false;
                                component.onBlur();
                            });
                        }
                        return true;

                    } else {
                        component.setFormInvalid();
                        component.$data.isFormSubmited = false;
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            },
            onValidate(name: string, isValid: boolean) {
                let component: any = this;

                if (this.$data.isGettingErrorMsg == true) {
                    this.$data.isGettingErrorMsg = false;
                    return;
                }
                if (isValid) {
                    this.setFormValid();
                } else {
                    component.$refs.form.validateField(name, (msg) => {
                        this.$data.isGettingErrorMsg = true;
                        this.$data.errorMessage = msg;
                        this.setFormInvalid();
                    });
                }
            },
            setFormValid() {
                let component: any = this;
                this.$data.isPopoverVisible = false;
                component.$refs.form.$el.classList.add('valid');
            },
            setFormInvalid() {
                let component: any = this;
                this.$data.isPopoverVisible = true;
                component.$refs.form.$el.classList.remove('valid');
                component.$refs.input.focus();
            }
        },
        // created() {
        //     debugger
        //     // alert("Created - Not a bug - If you still see this message - I'm working on it.")
        // },
        mounted() {
            debugger
            let component: any = this;
            component.setFormValid();
            component.$refs.input.$el.addEventListener('keypress', component.processInput);
            component.$refs.input.$el.addEventListener('keydown', component.processEscButtonPress);
            component.$refs.input.focus();
        },
        beforeUnmount() {
            this.$data.isPopoverVisible = false;
        }
    });
</script>
```

---

```
        const vueTemplate:any = createApp(template);
        const instance = vueTemplate.mount(config.element); // Breaking here
        // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'created' of undefined
        // and error:
        // Error: [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: el-input 
        //at <EditTextField>
        instance.$data.onValueChanged = config.onValueChanged;
        instance.$data.onEditModeExit = config.onEditModeExit;
        instance.$data.rules = config.validationRules;
```

config:

```
element: div.pointer.gantt-grid-value
onEditModeExit: ƒ ()
onValueChanged: ƒ (newValue)
validationRules: {value: Array(2)}
value: "0"
__proto__: Object
```

Didn't work:
`import EditTextField from './edit-text-field.vue';`
it breaks in this line
`createApp(EditTextField).mount(config.element);`
config.element : is element: div.pointer.gantt-grid-value
(element in the dom)

ERROR:

```
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:38 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: loading 
  at <EditTextField>
```

```
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:38 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: el-popover 
  at <EditTextField>
```

```
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:38 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: el-form-item 
  at <EditTextField>
```

```
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:38 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: el-form 
  at <EditTextField>
```

```
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:2911 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'created' of undefined
    at invokeDirectiveHook (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:2911)
    at mountElement (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3853)
    at processElement (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3822)
    at patch (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3742)
    at componentEffect (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4243)
    at reactiveEffect (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:42)
    at effect (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:17)
    at setupRenderEffect (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4208)
    at mountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4167)
    at processComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4127)
    at patch (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3745)
    at render (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4828)
    at mount (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3046)
    at Object.app.mount (runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js?830f:1234)
    at Function.EditTextFieldInitializer.InitEditTextField (edit-text-field.ts?b6bf:15)
    at Object.GanttInstance.editProgessValue (gantt-tab.ts?3a72:701)
```

FallowUp:

```
createApp(EditTextField).mount(config.element)
```

**It can't resolve html elements in template**
Like el-form-item and html errors above.

- creating a new app and i can't use my main.ts app

---

This code is working somehow.
but the issue is that:
I need to add all the imports again to make it work.
edit-text-field.ts

```
import template from './edit-text-field.vue';
import ElementPlus from 'element-plus';
import locale from "element-plus/lib/locale/lang/ru";
import { VueLocalizationPlugin } from "@/helpers/localization";

const comp = createApp(template);
        debugger
        comp.use(ElementPlus, { locale, size: "mini" }).use(VueLocalizationPlugin);
```

It's not good solution like in vue 2

Answer (score 1):

To create a component instance, use [`createApp()`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/global-api.html#createapp) on the component definition, and [`mount()`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-api.html#mount) it on an HTML element:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import MyComponent from '@/components/MyComponent.vue'

//...

let vueTemplate = createApp(MyComponent).mount(config.element)
```

[demo (simple)](https://codesandbox.io/s/creating-component-instance-in-vue-3-iunzd?file=/src/App.vue)

[demo (with Element UI)](https://codesandbox.io/s/creating-component-instance-in-vue-3-forked-owsj5?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:38 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: el-input 
  at <EditTextField>

Comment: and Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'created' of undefined

Comment: There is too much code and it's a big production code.
It used to work in vue 2 with a simple line  let vueTemplate = new template();
----
when it hits .mount(config.element) it's failling on create

Comment: Create a minimial reproducible example to help troubleshoot. You don't need to include your entire project. The error seems to indicate other problems in your code that are unrelated to the original problem, but we need to see the component code in order to determine that.

Comment: See the demo link in the answer for usage.

Comment: createApp(MyComponent).mount(config.element) this is creating a new app. and this code will not work instance.$data.rules = config.validationRules;